# Fetch records as per current time zone of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

I have date and time field in my **Request** Model and my current user should  see requests (request date and time not passed) as per his current date and time.

```
@requests = Request.where([date >= ? and user_id = ? and time >= ?, Date.current, current_user.id, Time.current])
```

So i have gonna through following link, from which i got information about how to get timezone from browser and store it in cookie.

http://thisbythem.com/blog/clientside-timezone-detection/

For easing things i have used following gem and checked my cookie, which gives me my timezone.

https://github.com/kbaum/browser-timezone-rails

Still it's not working as per my time zone, I have also tested it on server and local machine.
I can see those records which are out of my current time.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution it was logical mistake in my query, so answering right query:

1. date and time are both different fields so while querying on "date" and "time" fields, above query will only render records of today's date and future date but after my current time. So need change "time" field to "date&time" and only need to pass query for "time" field. eg.

   `@requests = Request.where([user_id = ? and time >= ?, Date.current, current_user.id, Time.zone.now])`

   gem "browser-timezone-rails" helps to convert and save local time in UTC.